# Intercepting a 400 Bad Request without stopping the application

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, http, error-handling

I've been trying to create a Login form in React. In this form, I submit a post request to an api, which then sends a response accordingly. However, in the api, invalid forms return a 400 status, which log an error to the console, unabling me to treat the invalid form. In my code, I'm trying to intercept this error using the catch method, so that I can do the necessary handling.

Here's the relevant code:

```js
class LoginModal extends Component {

  state = {
    email: "",
    password: ""
  }

  handleEmailChange = async event => {
    await this.setState({ email: event.target.value, });
  }
  handlePasswordChange = async event => {
    await this.setState({ password: event.target.value, });
  }

  redirect = path => {
    this.props.history.push(path);
  }

  handleSubmit = event => {
    event.preventDefault();

    const user = {
      email: this.state.email,
      password: this.state.password
    };

    api.post(`${api.url}/users/authenticate`, user)
      .then(res => {
          console.log("Succesful login.");
          this.redirect("/dashboard");
      })
      .catch(err => {
          console.log(err);
      })

  }

  render() {
    return (
      //*Render Code*
    );
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are misinterpreting the output of `console.log(err)` as an exception breaking your application. Try logging `err.response` instead of `err` and check if you can validate the request with that data.